# React native audio stops playing in background after a while

Tags: react-native, expo, internet-radio, expo-av

I tried to use expo AV and then I eject expo and tried react-native-radio-player but the issue still. it keeps playing for almost 5 minutes and then the sound stops.

How can I keep it playing in the background?